# Convert Recorded sound in iphone from one format to another say wav to mp3

Tags: iphone, mp3, wave, audiotoolbox

I am trying to record some audio and convert them to other sound formats. I am using AVAudioRecorder class to record and these are the recording settings I used..

```
 NSDictionary *recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
 [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];//kAudioFormatMicrosoftGSM,kAudioFormatLinearPCM
 [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:8000] forKey:AVSampleRateKey]; 
 [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
 [recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:16] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
 [recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey];
 [recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey];
```

Recording is working beautifully. Now I want to convert this sound file to mp3 format. Can I do this with AudioToolBox framework. I tried this

```
 AudioStreamBasicDescription sourceFormat,destinationFormat;
 //Setting up source Format setting..here wav
 sourceFormat.mSampleRate   = 8000.0;
 sourceFormat.mFormatID    = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
 sourceFormat.mFormatFlags   = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger ;
 sourceFormat.mBytesPerPacket  = 4;
 sourceFormat.mFramesPerPacket  = 1;
 sourceFormat.mBytesPerFrame   = 4;
 sourceFormat.mChannelsPerFrame  = 2;
 sourceFormat.mBitsPerChannel  = 16;

 destinationFormat.mSampleRate  = 8000.0;
 destinationFormat.mFormatID   = kAudioFormatMPEGLayer3;
 destinationFormat.mFormatFlags  = 0;
 destinationFormat.mBytesPerPacket = 4;
 destinationFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
 destinationFormat.mBytesPerFrame = 4;
 destinationFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 2;
 destinationFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 16;

 OSStatus returnCode     =     AudioConverterNew(&sourceFormat,&destinationFormat,&converter);
 if (returnCode) {
    NSLog(@"error getting converter : %d",returnCode);
    return;
 }
```

The function AudioConverterNew() is giving me error kAudioConverterErr_FormatNotSupported ('fmt'). I tried with different mFormatID and mFormatFlag combinations. But whenever one of the operant (source or destination) is mp3 I am getting this error. Now please help me with these questions.

1. Can we use AudioToolbox framework
   and functions to convert sounds
   between compressed and non
   compressed format (At present I want
   to convert between .wav and .mp3).
   In the AudioConverterNew
   documentation they are saying
   "Encoding and decoding between
   linear PCM and compressed formats is
   supported". But they are not
   specifically saying which compressed
   formats.
2. If the answer to question 1 is 'no'
   then which framework do I need to
   use to convert the sound between
   above mentioned formats?
3. Not related to above 2, but can
   anybody give me a link to any
   websites where information about
   different sound formats (wav,mp3,aac
   etc ) and their digital
   representations (cpm,lpcm etc) so
   that I can understand which uses
   what.

Answer (score 1):

Some answers

1. Yes, you can use the AudioToolbox framework to convert sounds except in the case of .mp3 format.  Due to copyright issues, mp3 is not available as a target format within the framework.
2. If you want to convert to mp3, you'll likely need to use the LAME libraries: http://lame.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/lame/lame/USAGE
3. Here's one for the .mp3 spec: http://mpgedit.org/mpgedit/mpeg_format/MP3Format.html
   The other formats you can find pretty easily via web search

Hope that helps